# Create responsive card decks in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a responsive card deck in Bootstrap. The card deck should display one card per row in mobile, 2 cards per row on tablet and 3 cards per row on desktop.

Below is my code -

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">2 Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">3 Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>  
</div>
```

The tablet part doesnt seem to work. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it'll help you

For reference go through the link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I am still getting the same output. I see three cards in tablet resolution

Comment: do you want 2 col in large devices or medium devices?

Comment: large - 3 , medium (tablet) - 2, mobile - 1

Comment: please check now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code but first inherit Bootstrap v4.1.3 in your page downloading link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you done ?